# You probably tried to upload too large file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was uploading some files which i used to upload regularly. Suddenly during uploading one file with same size, mysql gave error message "You probably tried to upload too large file".
No problem is, whenever i'm trying any query from phpmyadmin, its giving this error message "You probably tried to upload too large file" where its not related to any upload file.
If i connect Tableau to my sql then i can query from my database.
i can also query my database through navicat Lite Mysql. my query is not working at all from phpmyadmin.

---

i have already tried with related post/upload file size/memory limit setup in php.ini and its not giving me any solution.

I would like to fix my issue without re-instaliing my SQL setup? it will be great help if anyone can suggest any solution for my problem

Comment: Please post A) the query you are trying to use to upload the file B) what is the size in bytes of the file to be uploaded?  C) how many rows are in the file to be uploaded?  D) what is result of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet?.

Comment: My problem is triggered from file upload which i used to upload daily and all on a sudden this error appear. For upload file i use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, file size is 183469 KB. Once this error triggered, now even simple query is not working from my DB. Example: there is a test table where zero data. if i browse table from phpmyadmin  then it give "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)" which is ok, but if i run query from phpmyadmin (SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 1) then its giving error "You probably tried to upload too large file" where i am not uploading any file.

Comment: C) how many rows are in the file to be uploaded? D) what is result of SELECT @@max_allowed_packet; ? E) Please post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "test"; so we can see tbl summary information.  Thanks

Comment: Now i can't run any query in all table / database. it give below error immediately: You "probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit". Looks like a flag is set somewhere and i need help to find out to clear this error

Comment: Please post complete content of your php.ini file for analysis.  View profile for contact info and get in touch, please.  I will be back in office 20 hours.